# How should I translate "找你两块“？

Tags: translation, vocabulary

I understand that 两块 here means two yuan.

But how should I translate “找你两块”？ Thank you!

Comment: It means "to return ¥2.00 in change". If something costs ¥8.00 and you gave the shopkeeper ¥10.00, then the shopkeeper has 收你十塊，找你兩塊.

Comment: submit 找你 (widely used) to any number of online dictionaries (just  找 may take longer to find the proper answer among different applications of 找),e.g.  **bkrs**  :找你五毛。
Your change is fifty cents. **ichacha**  :这是找你的钱    here's your change

Answer (score 2):

To take a step back, a more complete exchange between the cashier and the customer could look something like this:

Customer: 這包餅乾多少錢？

Cashier: 這包餅乾8元。

Customer: 好，這裡10元。

Cashier: 謝謝，收你10元，找你2元。

Cashier takes $10 and gives back $2 in change.

找錢 means to give change, specifically, change owed given the difference in amount tendered and amount owing.